# payment for invoice nsoftware quickbooks

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I am using nSoftware to interact with QuickBooks. I am looking for nSoftware method to perform payment against Invoice. Pls let me know how to achieve this.

Dev Environment:-
ASP.Net 4.0, C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ReceivePayment** component can be used to enter customer payments into QuickBooks. Then, when adding a payment, specifying the **AppliedTo** property will direct the payment to a specific invoice. Note that you will need to set the **AutoApply** property to *aaCustom* when manually directing the payment. So, something like the following should work for you:

```cs
Receivepayment payment1 = new Receivepayment();
payment1.QBConnectionString = _qbConnectionString;
payment1.CustomerId = invoice1.CustomerId;
payment1.TransactionDate = "2013-06-26";
payment1.Amount = amount;
payment1.AutoApply = ReceivepaymentAutoApplies.aaCustom;
payment1.AppliedTo.Add(new AppliedTo() { RefId = invoice1.RefId, PaymentAmount = amount});
payment1.Add();
```

Multiple **AppliedTo** objects can be added to the **AppliedTo** collection to spread the payment across multiple invoices.